# How to know if a branch has been squashed into another

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

At work we squash feature branches instead of merging them to keep `release` branches clean and disconnected from the `feature` branch.

We're currently doing that with:

```
git checkout release
git merge --squash feature
git commit -m 'Squashed Feature 123'
```

But due to some **backend automation system** requirements, we would like to know what sha in the feature created the squash commit **without merging** and **without modifying the feature branch**.

The goal of the automation is to tell management that the `feature` has been squashed into `release` (regardless of conflicts and its resolution). The only consistent way of doing it would be to somehow "register" the `feature` HEAD sha into the squash commit. If the developer pushes more commits to the `feature`, the automation system would flag it as "unsquashed" again, since the `feature` HEAD now points to a sha that has not been squashed.

I've found 3 ways that could flag the squash commit so that the automation system could identify `feature` as squashed into `release`, but none are satisfactory:

1) `git merge -Xours feature` after the squash will create an additional commit that could serve to indicate to the automation system the `feature` sha that was merged into `release`. But now we have 2 commits plus the whole history just like a merge, so **not a solution** since we don't want the `feature` history.

2) `git replace --graft release release~1 feature` after the squash will make `feature` an ancestor of `release`. This works too, but just like 1), this will bring history again, which we want to avoid, so **not a solution either**.

3) `git commit -m 'squashed from [SHA=$feature_squashed_sha]'` the string can flag the automation system the squash commit is actually a merge from a certain commit. This could be a solution.... The problem is that getting that commit message right is **messy and prone to errors**.

Any insight on how to accomplish this in a manner that is both robust for the automation to parse and easy enough for users to implement into their merge workflow?

Now, we *don't have to* use a `git merge --squash`, any other non-mergeable approaches are welcome if it makes the squash point to its original sha in a consistent way.

Also, the automation system can be configured to run any command, as long as it gives the answer to the question **has the `feature` HEAD been squashed into `release`?**

Comment: Your replacement graft (option #2) is delete-able and does not copy from one repository to another by default, so I'm not sure what the objection is. You can automate option #3 by providing a script that runs `git merge --squash` followed by `git commit` with pre-provided message, and/or through a prepare-commit-msg hook. All methods other than "real merge" are user-mistake-prone though.

Comment: BTW, I will mention that use a different rule of thumb: *once a branch is squash-merged it must be immediately deleted.* (The original owner / merger can rename it instead if there's some plan to re-do the merge rather than pushing it.) This prevents additional development on it by mistake.

Comment: Deleting the feature branch makes a lot of sense. The only problem is that we may not be able to later revert the squashed changes without the feature branch.

Comment: @ojosilva your comment here about not being able to revert squash changes, makes it sound like you would want to revert a single commit that was made before the squash merge.  If that is so, then it shows you really do care about the individual commits made before the squash.  Squashing by its nature destroys that granularity of commit history.  If you care about those presquash commits, I think the question really becomes, why are we doing the squash in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about...

```
git checkout release
git checkout -b feature-123-abcd1234
git merge --squash feature-123
git checkout release
git merge --no-ff feature -123-abcd1234
```

Obviously this ends up with merges again, but they are maybe trivial enough to be allowed?

Another solution would be to store the squashed SHAs in a growing text file within the repository itself.

Finally, you could simply tag the feature branch each time you squash it...

Comment: `merge --no-ff` creates unnecessary history in the release, similar to `merge -Xours`. I like the tagging idea, it didn't occur to me! A little volatile though.

Comment: @ojosilva: Merge no-ff creates additional history, yes, but keeping history is what git is for. The DAG is the only permanent, immutable thing in git and is nothing to be afraid of. Maybe you could think about why you are so adamant about not having any "unnecessary" history. Have you been burnt by that in the past? Or is it just an arbitrary decision from some "IT architect"? My real suggestion would be to skip all of this and just do standard merge commits like everybody else, frankly.

Comment: Finally we're going with either **tag and delete the squashed branch** or **merge -Xours after you squash**. I agree that squashing, cherry-picking and any other alternatives to a plain merge are a bad idea, it's just that it's a reality that people are squashing and cherry-picking and we lose track of where the change came from. Definitely a squash breaks away from history and I'll be happy when we find a way to prevent people from doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Your chosen workflow seems a little odd. Say you've got three commits on `feature` that you want to squash into `release` - why not do

```
git checkout feature
git rebase release
git rebase --interactive HEAD~3   # (squash the latest two commits into the third)
git checkout release
git merge release                 # (fast-forward merge to keep commit history clean)
git checkout -
...continue working on feature...
```

This way, you avoid merge commits. The above to me seems to be equivalent to what you're doing, except that  a simple `git log release..feature` is enough to tell you which commits aren't yet squashed into `release`.

After all, the spirit of `git merge --squash` is to **kill off** `feature` when integrating it into `release`. What you're trying to do is much closer to a rebase.

If you are married to the `git merge --squash` workflow, create a [lightweight tag](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) and have developers run `git tag -a squashed` prior to squash-merging.

(Disclaimer: I'm relatively new to git.)

Comment: No, we're not married to that workflow. But we were trying to keep away from rebasing feature branches, which has lots of problems, like feature scrambling and constant loss of development history. But I agree, squash and deleting the branch may be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

> The goal of the automation is to tell management that the `feature` has been squashed into `release` (regardless of conflicts and its resolution).

This means that you can’t use git-cherry(1) since it can’t detect cherry-picks/squashes in the face of possible conflicts.

I think [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104323/how-to-know-if-a-branch-has-been-squashed-into-another#comment81159426_47104323) is correct; the only choice given these constraints is to add metadata to your commits, i.e. the third option.

> The problem is that getting that commit message right is **messy and prone to errors**.

Then you should automate the metadata-tagging.

This script will let the user write a commit message and then add two [trailers](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-interpret-trailers) with the branch name and the SHA1 of the the tip of that branch:

```
#!/bin/sh

branch=$(git branch --show-current)
git checkout release
message=$(mktemp)
editor=$(git var GIT_EDITOR)
printf "\n\n# Write a message for your squash merge above\n" > $message
# FIXME Script should error out if the user doesn’t write anything
$editor $message
git merge --squash $branch
squashed_from_sha1=$(git rev-parse $branch)
final_message=$(mktemp)
git interpret-trailers \
    --trailer="Squashed-from-branch: $branch" \
    --trailer="Squashed-from-sha1: $squashed_from_sha1" \
    <$message > $final_message
git commit -F $final_message --cleanup=strip
```

For example:

```
commit 8aa50b19861c0d405c29bd3911e152df8e04689d (HEAD -> release)
Author: Victor Version Control <vvc@vcs.org>
Date:   Tue Apr 11 19:52:46 2023 +0200

    Feature X

    I spent two weeks implementing this (ugh) so I don’t want to write
    any more about it now…

    Squashed-from-branch: x
    Squashed-from-sha1: 7a6d81d37f5190405ba582a95d712add8392babc
```

To get/parse the two values:

```
git log -1 --format="%(trailers:key=squashed-from-branch,valueonly)" <sha1>
git log -1 --format="%(trailers:key=squashed-from-sha1,valueonly)" <sha1>
```

#### Concerns

As you’ve noted yourself in the comments, this is not a great approach at all. Tracking “squash merges” and cherry-picks is tedious, and you won’t get much help from git(1) (especially with regards to squash merges).

One feature requirement was tracking the branch that was squashed from. But is that immortal? Because branch names like `new-dialogs` are very ephemeral and something you probably want to reuse for another feature a year from now or so. Should that be handled?